# how to create splash screen for blackberry storm

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to made an application.
When i open this application first it display on image for 10 seconds and after that it go to another screen automatically.

How it is possible Please give the help.

Comment: what is minimum os version you are using

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want a splash screen for 10seconds? Thats like forever..

But I would do it by creating a screen like this:

```
public class SplashScreen extends MainScreen {
    public SplashScreen() {
        super();
        this.setTitle("loading...");
        // add you splash screen images or whatever here

        final Screen me = this;
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                // do something that takes a long time
                try { Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (Exception e) {}

                synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
                    Screen next = new YourNextScreen(); // replace with your next screen here
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(next);
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(me);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Then push it onto the stack from your `UiApplcation` class.

Answer (score 2):

Create a MainScreen where you will add a bitmap field to it. And then run a Thread in it like the following:

```
Thread th = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    try { Thread.sleep(10000); } catch (Exception ex) { }
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater ( new Runnable() { public void run () {
      //push your screen
      close();
    }});
  }
};
th.start();
```